# Recorrer con un for los elementos child de un parent node pero que la funcion se agregue especificamente al child clickeado

Tags: javascript

```
var ViewDelett0element = function(){
for (var p = 0; p <= List.children.length -1; p++) {
List.children[p].addEventListener("click", function(){List.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element")});}
};
```

Porfavor necesito ayuda :Actualmente estoy tratando de agregar la funcion (ViewDelett0element) a un especifico elemento que de click , por ahora la funcion se recorre atodos los elementos child con el for agregandoles la funcion que leda la clase al elemento padre , pero no encuentro la manera de agregarselo solo al child que clikie especificamente ya trate de todo acontinuacion los codigos intento que fracasaron y no son correctos o no trabajan a como crei.

```
var ViewDelett0element = function(){
for (var p = 0; p <= List.children.length -1; p++) {
List.children[p].addEventListener("click", function(){List.child(Nodes[p]).setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element")});}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No te comprendo muy bien, espero que te ayude

en dado caso de que no te sea de ayuda, déjame un comentario mejor explicado.

```js
var List = document.querySelector('#list');

var ViewDelett0element = function() {
    for (var p = 0; p <= List.children.length - 1; p++) {
        List.children[p].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element")
        });
    }
};

ViewDelett0element();
```

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li{
  padding:.5em;
  margin:.3em;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  display:nlock;
}

.ViewDelett0element{
  background:#f00;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li><span>1</span></li>
<li><span>2</span></li>
<li><span>3</span></li>
<li><span>4</span></li>
<li><span>5</span></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Wow  this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element") con eso fue suficiente muchas gracias no sabia que no es necesario tener que referirse al child dentro del parent node (= solo con this XD exelente muchas gracias

Comment: ahhahahahaha de nada amigo XD, cualquier ayuda puedes preguntarme :D